# Impact of heat on unshielded data cables

Tags: cables, thermal, signal-integrity, ribbon-cable

How does heat impact the signaling performance of unshielded ribbon/flexible flat cables?

Background: I'm modding a camera to improve thermal performance by adding thermal pads between the heatsink and the camera case.  The thermal pads are not electrically conductive, but I'm puzzled as to why the manufacturer didn't do this in the first place.  Given that there is direct contact between the primary cable (directly above box B) I don't think the cables are at risk of overheating. The lack of thermal pads in square A (where there is no cabling) suggests this is just cost optimizing.

[image: Sony ZV-E10 camera with back removed, exposing internals]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Those are flat-flex cables, not ribbon cables.

Comment: Note that silicone thermal pads release oil - so make sure that there is no way for that to get inside the lens or onto the imaging sensor.

Comment: "Just cost cutting" is not just cost cutting. It is an important effort to make a device cost competitive in the market.  If the camera was more expensive than similar cameras, would you really be looking at that camera or would you have purchased a different camera?

Comment: @AndrewMorton The stock heat sink does use *some* thermal pads, but I don't know if a larger number of them would be problematic and have questions about how thermal pads degrade over time....

Comment: @GTElectronics Good point: over-engineering is Muda!  I can't fit a full explanation in here, but I have [reason to believe](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1385126-modding-sony-zv-e10/) this is artificial market segmentation.  However, I changed the question to use the more neutral "cost optimize" wording.